# Entity Framework SaveChanges is called but its not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code. When I trace the code I see that `City` is not null, it's values changes then `SaveChanges` is called but changes are not saved. there are about hundreds of similar code in this project and all of them works. what the problem can be here?

```
     using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
        long id = (long)((string)data.data[i].id).ParseLong();
        City city = db.Cities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (city != null)
            {
            city.FromLat = data.data[i].fromlat;
            city.ToLat = data.data[i].tolat;
            city.FromLng = data.data[i].fromlng;
            city.ToLng = data.data[i].tolng;
            if (city.FromLat > city.ToLat) More.Swap(ref city.ToLat, ref city.FromLat);
            if (city.FromLng > city.ToLng) More.Swap(ref city.FromLng, ref city.ToLng);
            db.SaveChanges();
            }
       }
```

Comment: What SQL is passed to the database, if any?

Comment: @stuartd nothing. this is the whole code.

Comment: is there any exceptions ?

Comment: @Sampath nope. that is the problem. If there were an ecxeption it woud give me a hint about what is wrong

Comment: can you test without these 2 lines ? I mean `commenting out` those and see what happen.`if (city.FromLat > city.ToLat) More.Swap(ref city.ToLat, ref city.FromLat);
            if (city.FromLng > city.ToLng) More.Swap(ref city.FromLng, ref city.ToLng);`

Comment: Can you please check what is the output of `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Are you sure that city is not null? Have you actually debugged your code to ensure that the code reaches the inside of the `if` block or is this the code responsible and you assume that it is not null and hitting that point.

Comment: @Eldho you mean like :`int a = db.SaveChanges();` it returns 0. Is there anyway that city gets deattached?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani There is no row effected in the SQL. that why you get 0 as return.

Comment: Can you please try something like this. `city.Fromlang = "somevalue"` Only this line and `savechanges()`

Comment: @Igor as I said in the question i trace the code it it not null, the values changes and `SaveChanges()` is called

Comment: Then you should add the following to your question: 1) the mapping code for the entity in question, 2) a screen shot of the state of the entity instance when the entity is retrieved from the database, 3) a screenshot of the entity immediately before `db.SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: @Eldho I tried just with one line as you said and I also tried attaching it to database again (also I knew that its already attached) but not working. It drives me crazy. Its a simple line of code that I have written many like this before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided your model, but using the `ref` keyword in these lines:

```
if (city.FromLat > city.ToLat) More.Swap(ref city.ToLat, ref city.FromLat);
if (city.FromLng > city.ToLng) More.Swap(ref city.FromLng, ref city.ToLng);
```

clearly indicates that `FromLat`, `ToLat`, `FromLng` and `ToLng` members are **fields**, thus not mapped to database columns. Make them **properties** and use different code for swapping (a bit longer, but working):

```
if (city.FromLat > city.ToLat) { var temp = city.FromLat; city.FromLat = city.ToLat; city.ToLat = temp; };
if (city.FromLng > city.ToLng) { var temp = city.FromLng; city.FromLng = city.ToLng; city.ToLng = temp; };
```

Comment: You are a genius. I had forgotton `{get; set;}` in `public Nullable<double> FromLat { get; set; }` but I don't know why it still isn't working . but I get that I should check the mapping

Comment: If you are using automatic migrations with `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` set `true`, most probably your original data from those columns is gone (what happened in my test environment while testing before answering). After making them properties again, my columns were brought back, filled with zeroes (or `null`s)

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the item to its collection (`db.Cities.Add(city)`).

If you want to update the entity:

```
db.Entry(city).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.Entry(city).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Should do the trick.

Add this right before savechanges

Comment: IMHO Context will do the tracking by default. Its redundant to mark as modified in this scenario

Comment: no it didn't. when city's properties are changed the `EntityState.Modified` should change automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the state to modified via

```
db.Entry(city).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Or you can manually set each field that has changed as modified.